# Can I put a list of one value in a multivalued provider in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to put in Solr a multivalued provider with dynamic values. In [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html) I found this explanation: "If true, indicates that a single document might contain multiple values for this field type". When I try to put a list of Field Values with more then one value I have success, but when I try simulate a list of one value, nothing happends.

My code is below:

```
public class ArezzoCoCategoriesAvailableValueProvider extends AbstractPropertyFieldValueProvider implements FieldValueProvider,
    Serializable {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ArezzoCoCategoriesAvailableValueProvider.class);

private FieldNameProvider fieldNameProvider;
private ArezzoCoCategoryService categoryService;
private UrlResolver<CategoryModel> categoryModelUrlResolver;

private final Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");

@Override
public Collection<FieldValue> getFieldValues(IndexConfig indexConfig, IndexedProperty indexedProperty, Object model) throws FieldValueProviderException {
    if (model instanceof CategoryModel) {
        final String fieldName = getFieldNameProvider().getFieldName(indexedProperty, null, FieldNameProvider.FieldType.INDEX);
        List<FieldValue> values = new ArrayList<>();
        CategoryModel category = (CategoryModel) model;

        String categoryUrl = getCategoryModelUrlResolver().resolve(category);
        String categoryName = category.getName(locale);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(categoryName) || StringUtils.isEmpty(categoryUrl)) {
            LOG.error("The cateogry with code: " + category.getCode() + " has problems with Name or Url.");
            return values;
        }

        CategoryEntryData categoryEntry = createNewCategoryEntryData(categoryName, categoryUrl);
        values.add(new FieldValue(fieldName, getJsonObject(categoryEntry, LOG)));

        if (category.getBcMainCategory() > 0) {
            List<CategoryModel> filterCategories = getCategoryService().getFilterCategoriesWithProductsInCommon(category, category.getCatalogVersion());
            filterCategories.forEach(cat -> {
                CategoryEntryData categoryEntryData = createNewCategoryEntryData(createNameWithFilter(categoryName, cat.getName(locale), getConnectionTerm(cat.getSupercategories())), createUrlWithFilter(categoryUrl, cat));
                values.add(new FieldValue(fieldName, getJsonObject(categoryEntryData, LOG)));
            });
        }
        return values;
    } else {
        throw new FieldValueProviderException("Cannot Generate url for this specific category");
    }
}

public FieldNameProvider getFieldNameProvider() {
    return fieldNameProvider;
}

public void setFieldNameProvider(FieldNameProvider fieldNameProvider) {
    this.fieldNameProvider = fieldNameProvider;
}

public ArezzoCoCategoryService getCategoryService() {
    return categoryService;
}

public void setCategoryService(ArezzoCoCategoryService categoryService) {
    this.categoryService = categoryService;
}

public UrlResolver<CategoryModel> getCategoryModelUrlResolver() {
    return categoryModelUrlResolver;
}

public void setCategoryModelUrlResolver(UrlResolver<CategoryModel> categoryModelUrlResolver) {
    this.categoryModelUrlResolver = categoryModelUrlResolver;
}
```

Debuging my code I can see the provider is correctly populating a list of Field Values (with one item):

[image]

But when I access Solr that property not exists when the list have just one item:

[image]

My impex with the configuration of a property is this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique = true]; name[unique = true] ; type(code); sortableType(code); currency[default = false]; localized[default = false]; multiValue; useForSpellchecking[default = false]; useForAutocomplete[default = false]; fieldValueProvider; valueProviderParameter;displayName[lang=pt];displayName[lang=en];ftsQuery;ftsQueryBoost;ftsWildcardQuery;ftsWildcardQueryBoost;ftsPhraseQuery;ftsPhraseQueryBoost;includeInResponse[default = true];
                             ; $solrIndexedType ; categories_available                  ; string    ;              ; ; true;true;true;true; arezzoCoCategoriesAvailableValueProvider   ;   ;Categorias    ;Categories    ;true   ;100,00  ;true ;50,00;true;25,00 ;
```

Solr version: 7.1.0
Hybris version: 6.6.0.17

So, my question is: can I put a list of one value in a multivalued provider in Solr? I make a mistake configuring the property?

SOLUCTION:
There is not wrong with the code above. The error is on method `getJsonObject(...)` and I solved. Well, if someone need help to create a provider with a multivalued, this is an example.

Comment: From the Solr side - there is nothing wrong about having a single value in a multi-valued field list, so it's supported properly on the Solr side at least. I'm not familiar with how Hybris integrates with Solr.

Comment: Can you give us the code, where you are searching in the SOLR index? To see what parameters you have.

Comment: Can you share what minor patch you are using? e.g. 1905.15?

Comment: Also, agree with Mafick. Share the Java code for arezzoCoCategoriesAvailableValueProvider. This looks custom, not OOTB.

Comment: sure, updated with the code

Comment: Hi @Lucas

Can you try Resolver instead of provider,I hope understood your question.

you want output like this 
 "allowedProductUserGroups_string_mv":["dr4",
          "cd9",
          "cd15"]
when multi-value is true.

Comment: is the index throwing any kind of error after executing you provider? @LucasDiehl

Comment: @RaushanKumar actualy I put like this already, but the values go from to Solr just when have more then one item inside list.

Comment: @Damian229 I didn't find any error during and after the execution